# Strange issue with Django form and initial values

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm going crazy trying to understand why the default value that I defined using "initial" in my form are not printed in my template. The form is something like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # ...
    proximity = forms.IntegerField(required=False, initial=50)
```

in my template:

```
{{ myForm.proximity }}
```

prints:

```
<input id="id_proximity" name="proximity" type="number">
```

**BUT**, if I run the following in the shell:

```
print MyForm()
```

In the output I find:

```
<input id="id_proximity" name="proximity" type="number" value="50" />
```

that is what I was expecting in my template! Why in the shell it works and in the template it doesn't?

(I'm using Django 1.6)

**SOLVED!**

I was initializing the form in this way in my view:

```
MyForm(self.request.GET)
```

and since there is no data in GET the initial is replaced with None :P

Comment: What Django version is this?

Comment: The version is: Django 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right.. it take me 30 minutes to solve:)
we can read the django/forms/fields.py in  source code of django as follow:

```
# initial -- A value to use in this Field's initial display. This value
#            is *not* used as a fallback if data isn't given.
```

and the forms.Form.**_*init*_** first param is data, so it means that you set the data and the initial will be used as a fallback.:)